# Google Voice Curl command to mark texts as read

Tags: c++, c, curl, google-voice

So right now I am using someone elses google voice API but I think the API is out of date so I am trying to fix it up.
The only functioning aspect of their API is that it is able to read a message. That is what I need it to do but I also need it to mark it as read.
So I need to figure out the proper way to send the curl command to mark the message as read.

I was curious if anyone knows the command or knows how to find out the command needed.